# Pass additional parameter with async upload

Tags: ajax, wp-admin, uploads

The following image:

[image]

is showing what i want to archive. It shows the default admin upload widget in where i added a checkbox that once checked would pass an additional parameter with the async upload script. So far i havent had any luck figuring out how this can be achieved. Anybody any idea?

Comment: actually i found it in overwritting wpUploaderInit.multipart_params

Comment: You can write your own answer to this question (and need to wait a couple of days to accept it, I think). This way it will be easier for future visitors to see the solution and you'll be able to post about it in more detail